# What's the point of anti theft if recovery wipe can clear it?

Tags: factory-reset, hard-reset, anti-theft

Seriously how is an anti theft supposed to protect your device?

A thief can either just boot in recovery and erase data partition and poof anti theft is gone for good.

And with firmware tools like odin easily available the thief can even overrite the in firmware anti theft.

Did Nokia did it better by limiting control over non end user functions?

Comment: Starting from Android 5.0, there is a feature called FRP that block the access to a device if it was reset in recovery or via android device manager. FRP can be bypassed. Samsung has its own FRP which is hard to bypass on marshmallow.

Comment: Ever thought about data protection? If using the "found" device requires to wipe it, at least your personal data are protected (to a degree, that is, as usually the SD card is skipped and there's always forensics).

Comment: @Izzy You don't need anti-theft for that really, a home-screen password lock that perpetrator is unable to break should be enough to prompt him to wipe, given that you are not some VIP whose data is thief after

Comment: There's that, true. Still, until switched off, you have some advantage. And there are thieves and thieves – some are clever, some are not ;) No such thing as perfect safety, though.